# React-Redux history.query is truncated for spaced query parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When i route in my app to :

```
www.myApp.com/main?subCategory=Books,%20Magazines%20&%20Papers
```

then my query param is truncated even though i use decodeURIComponent():

```
{subCategory} = location.query; // "Books, Magazines "
```

(Instead of "Books, Magazines & Papers")

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

& is a special character that is used to separate query string parameters. You'll have to replace & with %26, which encodes it.